# Buggy javascript button event handler

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a music player on my page. I have a table with each row representing a song with the first element being a button whose id is the url of the song.

```
        <tbody>
        {% for e in entries %}
            <tr>
                <td><button class="song btn" id="{{ e.url }}"><i class="icon-play-circle"></i></button></td>
                <td>{{ e.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.artist }}</td> 
                <td>{{ e.features }}</td>
                <td>{{ e.genre }}</td>
                <td><a href="/myapp/editsong/{{ e.id }}">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

I am trying to implement some javascript to change the src of a HTML5 audio element on the page when a button is clicked to its id:

```
$("button.song").on("click", function(event){
    if (audio.src != event.target.id)
    {
      audio.src = event.target.id;
      play.className = 'btn btn-success';
      pause.className = 'btn';
      audio.play();
  }
});
```

This implementation works somewhat, but is very buggy. Sometimes clicking a button will change the audio element src to blank and I will have to click the button multiple times.

Comment: What is `audio.src`? and why do you need this check: `if (audio.src != event.target.id)`?

Comment: I imagine so you cannot select the current song from the list?

Comment: @rlemon. Yes, they can't find the  _Britney Spears_ album...

Comment: Why would you us a button with the ID of the url instead of using an anchor tag? Also, the `<i>` tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure, but you should use an other attribute to store the URL to the song that you are trying to run, if my memory does not fails me, there are restrictions regarding what's the "range" of characters allowed for the id attr.

Perhaps the value attribute does't have this limitations. Though I would use something more "alphanumeric only" as a reference to an object/array and then use that to get the value.

Greetings!
Gonzalo G.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameter, event.target.id by using javascript alerts for debugging. Click on the  buttons to see what the values are for each audio.

```
if (audio.src != event.target.id)
...
```

Comment: @Kev, Check the parameter try to debug... Do you consider it to be an answer? I can't believe you declined! At most it's a comment(Just like I did.)